# Launch Managed Bootstrapper Application EXE in Admin Privilege

Tags: wix, burn, wix3

I have crated an MBA setup in WiX 3.11. In my setup UI, I need to access registry and will show that registry values in UI. If I am running the setup in admin mode (Right-Click -> "Run as Admin"), setup reads the registry entry. But If it is not in admin mode it shows error. 
is there any options available in WiX Burn to launch setup in UAC on setup double click?

Thanks

Comment: How are you reading the registry? If it's via code, can you ask for fewer permissions when opening the key? Typically administrative privileges should not be required for this.

Comment: Reading registry values using C# code.

Comment: Then I would suggest confirming that C# registry code works when not elevated. (Perhaps debug it in a standalone app.) Making the bootstrap always elevate should be a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's not a built-in way to make a MBA run elevated. This is something the WiX maintainers have said they don't want to do.  Generally, you can most things without it (with the big exception of querying IIS settings) and let you're MSI elevate themselves when they install (if it's needed).

However, there are times when you really do need the MBA itself to elevate.  Since you can't elevate an already-running process, you generally have two options:

- modify the MBA's embedded manifest file to force it to elevate immediately
- have the MBA process spin up another background process that runs elevated and have the two processes communicate back and forth.

I've used a tool like [ResourceTuner Console](http://www.heaventools.com/rtconsole-sample-script-edit-manifest.htm) to modify the manifest file after it's built, but be warned that sometimes this results in an MBA that fails to find it's embedded MSIs.  It also creates major pain points if you are also using code signing with your installer, as modifying the MBA will invalidate your signature.